# How do I check the dependencies of an older version of a gem?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, rubygems

How do I check the dependencies of an older version of a gem?  The 'gem dependency' command appears to only work with the newest version, despite having a -v option (version) in the 'gem help dependency' page.

Here's a list of all the available versions:

```
gem list -all -r activesupport

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

activesupport (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.12, 3.0.11, 3.0.10, 3.0.9, 3.0.8, 3.0.7, 3.0.6, 3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.14, 2.3.12, 2.3.11, 2.3.10, 2.3.9, 2.3.8, 2.3.7, 2.3.6, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.5, 2.0.4, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
activesupport-cascadestore (0.0.2, 0.0.1)
```

However, I can't seem to get the dependencies for older versions of the gem.

```
gem dependency activesupport -r -v 3.2.3
Gem activesupport-3.2.3
  i18n (~> 0.6, runtime)
  multi_json (~> 1.0, runtime)

gem dependency activesupport -r -v 1.4.2
No gems found matching activesupport (= 1.4.2)

gem dependency activesupport -r -v 1.4.1
No gems found matching activesupport (= 1.4.1)
```

..and here's a post circa 2009 that encounters the same problem:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/194703

relevant: http://xkcd.com/979/

Does anybody have an alternate way to check the dependencies of an older version of a gem?

EDIT: Still looking for a way to find *all* dependencies of a an older version of a gem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not as convenient as using RubyGems through the command line, but you can find that information on [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/) when browsing through gems.

For example, ActiveSupport [3.2.0.rc1](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/3.2.0.rc1) introduced a dependency on i18n, while [3.1.0.beta1](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/3.1.0.beta1) introduced the dependency on multi_json.

Comment: This was helpful, and thanks for looking through the listed versions for their dependencies.  However, the website only lists external dependencies - I was actually hoping to find the version that started requiring `activesupport (>= 2.3.11, runtime)`

Comment: There are actually a lot more dependencies that are not listed on rubygems: 
`Gem activemerchant-1.23.0
  active_utils (>= 1.0.2, runtime)
  activesupport (>= 2.3.11, runtime)
  builder (>= 2.0.0, runtime)
  i18n (>= 0, runtime)
  json (>= 1.5.1, runtime)
  mocha (~> 0.11.3, development)
  money (>= 0, runtime)
  nokogiri (>= 0, runtime)
  rails (>= 2.3.11, development)
  rake (>= 0, development)
  rubigen (>= 0, development)`